# JQuery works on fiddle but on actual html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/2858/

The code on the fiddle works but when I run it on a .html file, nothing is displayed at all.

> Code in html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<tr> 
    <td>
        <select id="pay-type" name="form_select" class="form-control" onchange="test()">
            <option value="hand">Cash on Hand</option>
            <option value="palawan">Palawan Express</option>
            <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
            <option value="bdo">BDO Master Card</option>
            <option value="xoom">Xoom.com</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="hand" class="pay-type" style="display:none"> You have selected onhand </div>
        <div id="palawan" class="pay-type" style="display:none"> You have selected palawan </div>
        <div id="paypal" class="pay-type" style="display:none"> You have selected paypal </div>     
        <div id="bdo" class="pay-type" style="display:none"> You have selected BDO </div>   
        <div id="xoom" class="pay-type" style="display:none"> You have selected xoom </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

> Code in jquery.js

```
$(function test() 
{
    $('#pay-type').change(function(){
        $('.pay-type').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

I'm not really good at jquery so I do not really know what I am doing wrong. And my situation in comparison to the other questions with the same thought is kind of different.

Comment: wrap your jquery code in  `$(document).ready(function(){  //YOUR CODE  });`

Comment: When you load your page in browser Press F12 do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent There is already a document ready wrapper

Comment: Where is your jQuery include!!! It is not magically included. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: YURGH, inline javascript and inline CSS............ and `jquery.js` that is not jQuery :)

Comment: Error in console are
GET http://localhost/js/jquery.js 
GET http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: Well your JavaScript file is not where you say it is. But once you get that straightened out, it still will not run since you did not include the jQuery core library like I mentioned 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Already fixed it. I'm sorry for such a disappointing question and that I am expected to ask questions above amateur level.

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using a `$` function. It depends on jQuery, but you haven't loaded jQuery. You can get it from [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/).

To avoid confusion, you should rename your existing `jquery.js` to something that describes its purpose (e.g. `show-pay-type.js`) instead of the library that it depends on.

Comment: From posted code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @A.Wolff — Keep reading. The contents of that file are described later in the question. It contains the code that depends on jQuery, not jQuery itself.

Comment: My bad! Didn't saw that ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff — It's a very misleading filename :)